# Send inline keyboard to Telegram group using JS

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm using JavaScript to send a message to Telegram using the Telegram Bot API

```js
const url = `https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot_token>/sendMessage?chat_id=${chat_id}&text=${message}`
const data = await fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json())
```

I want to send an inline keyboard so I tried

```js
const message='{"reply_markup":{{\"inline_keyboard\": [[{ \text" : " Press here", "callback_data" : "TEST" }]]}}}'
```

But I got to Telegram

```json
{"reply_markup":{{"inline_keyboard": [[{  ext" : " Press here", "callback_data" : "TEST" }]]}}}
```

How can I fix that to get the keyboard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create the keyboard using strings, use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert it to a url-acceptable format.

Consider the example below, a function called `sendMessage` that accepts a required `chat_id` and a required `message`.
Optionally, pass a `keyboard` as Javascript object that is added to the url as `reply_markup`

```js
const keyboard = {
  "inline_keyboard": [
    [
      { text: "Press here", callback_data: "TEST" }
    ]
  ]
};

sendMessage(1234, 'hoi', keyboard);

function sendMessage(chat_id, message, keyboard = null) {
    const bot_token = '859163.........';
    let url = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${bot_token}/sendMessage?chat_id=${chat_id}&text=${message}`;
    if (keyboard) {
        url += '&reply_markup=' + JSON.stringify(keyboard);
    }
    fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json()).then(j => console.log(j));
}
```

---

Result:

[image]